# ODB2 Fuel Level 2004 Chrysler Town & Country

Tags: obd-ii, chrysler, town-and-country

I am wondering if anyone knows if a 2004 Chrysler Town & Country supports Fuel Level over ODB2.  I have been unable to find a list of which vehicles do/don't support this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From memory I believe that it does although over OBD2 is rather vague. It requires a scan tool that can access the data from the gauge cluster. It won't be available in the standard OBD2 stream.

Comment: Do you have any references showing any of this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. From memory i diagnosed a T&C fuel level problem and could bring the PID up on a scan tool. The scan tool was a SnapOn Solus and i was not looking at the generic OBD2 data stream.